# Django authentication and permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I posted a question on SO regarding Django authentication and permissions even though it's already there. My question is ,

I have a backend ready with a lot of views, models and serializers from DRF. Now I want to apply authentication to my app and create RESTful apis that are consumed at the front-end. So the doubts that I have

- How does authentication work? Does Django create different model tables for each of its user?
- If so, how do I retrieve data per user from Django?

Now comes the second case

- If above two are true, then how do I use permission in DRF to serve only the data that is relevant to a particular user?

I hope my questions are clear. If not, suggest me edits.
I'd also like some examples(if any) on how does this all happens.

Also, if you want to see the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484907/django-authentication-with-drf).

Answer (score 0):

Django uses table `auth_user` to save user and password

Django has an API to check `is_authenticated`

---

Django rest framework uses table `authtoken_token`

Django rest framework has an API `rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token` for the same purpose

In DRF, for permissions you can do something like below..

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    User Detail API
    """
    permission_classes = ("check_permission1", "check_permission2",) ### you can define your permissions using this
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does authentication work? Does Django create different model tables for each of its user?

No, Django does not create different model tables for each of its users. The users itself are stored as entry in the `User`-Model. So to have data for each user you have to add a foreign-key in your data model to a particular user.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    text = models.TextField()
```

So once your user is logged in (authenticated) you simply filter the Post-model according to the logged in user.
In DRF you can do this filtering with permissions:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to see it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.author == request.user
```

I hope this helps

Comment: So right now, I have around ten different models and some of them have their own one to many relationships. That said, I'd have to add a relationship to every model that I have with 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'? Also, the second snippet is for the class that serve data to the serializer? And I'm using function based views right now, I think the application remains the same

Comment: The most important point to understand is, that you have to manage the association between your models and the users yourself and that Django does not in any way create model instances per user itself.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but you did not answer any of the questions I asked above rather you gave a broad explanation of what I need to study

Comment: You asked broad questions so you get a broad explanation

Comment: The questions in my comment are really rather a yes or no. I don't see them having broad answers. If so, you could explain a little more or agree/disagree and tell me why I'm right or wrong. That would really help.

Comment: So the answer to the first question is no. As stated in my response. The other two question are asked "If so" and "If above two are true" which does not make sense to answer when already the first answer is "no"...